# Pandas Resample DateTime that spans 2 days, and week start at Sunday

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have the function below that reads in a csv file and chunks the data into Days, Weeks, and Months.

My issue is that the days are chunked 24 hrs from a normal 12 am. However, the data should be chunked from 4pm - 4pm (going into the next day).

In addition, the dt.week makes a Monday starting week since the data begins on Monday. I want to default to Sunday 4pm -Friday 4pm as one week. I can do this naively going by the index and I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

**Goal: I want to make a list of dataframes that chunk this 5 min data (see df.head())  in days, weeks and months.** For days, I need the day to start at 4pm and continue till 4pm the next day. For weeks, I want the week to start on Sunday and the issue is that since the data begins on Monday it wants to separate weeks from Mondays.

```
def read_in_files(file_names):
    """
    1. Read the csv files to memory into a pandas dataframe with pd.read_csv
    2. separate the df into year, month, and date objects
    3. It also chunks the data by single day
    """
    import os
    import pandas as pd

    file1 = pd.read_csv(file_names, parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])

    df = pd.DataFrame(file1)

# Week is defined as sunday 4pm to Friday 4pm --not working correctly
# this is a timestamp obj
    df['year'], df['month'] = df['Date_Time'].dt.year, df['Date_time'].dt.month
    df['date'] = df['Date_Time'].dt.day
    df['week'] = df['Date_Time'].dt.week

    """
    these three lines below chunk the data by dates
    """
    df_single_day = []
    for group in df.groupby(df.Date_Time, sort=False):
        df_single_day.append(group[1])

    df_single_week = []
    for group in df.groupby(['week', 'year'], sort=False):
        df_single_week.append(group[1])

    df_single_month = []
        for group in df.groupby(['month', 'year'], sort=False):
        df_single_month.append(group[1])

    return df df_single_day, df_single_week, df_single_month
```

**Example output**

df_single_day[0].tail(5)

Out[11]:

```
    Unnamed: 0  Symbol     Date_Time     Open    High     Low   Close  \
90          91  ABCDEF 2008-05-06 23:35  0.9480  0.9483  0.9477  0.9480   
91          92  ABCDEF 2008-05-06 23:40  0.9479  0.9482  0.9476  0.9479   
92          93  ABCDEF 2008-05-06 23:45  0.9478  0.9481  0.9474  0.9477   
93          94  ABCDEF 2008-05-06 23:50  0.9477  0.9481  0.9472  0.9478   
94          95  ABCDEF 2008-05-06 23:55  0.9479  0.9481  0.9475  0.9478   
year  month  date  week  
90  2008      5     6    19  
91  2008      5     6    19  
92  2008      5     6    19  
93  2008      5     6    19  
94  2008      5     6    19
```

df_single_day[1].head(5)

Out[14]:

```
    Unnamed: 0  Symbol     Date_Time     Open    High     Low   Close  \
95          96  ABCDEF 2008-05-07 00:00  0.9478  0.9483  0.9475  0.9481   
96          97  ABCDEF 2008-05-07 00:05  0.9481  0.9484  0.9479  0.9484   
97          98  ABCDEF 2008-05-07 00:10  0.9482  0.9485  0.9480  0.9482   
98          99  ABCDEF 2008-05-07 00:15  0.9482  0.9485  0.9478  0.9483   
99         100  ABCDEF 2008-05-07 00:20  0.9483  0.9485  0.9480  0.9484   
    year  month  date  week  
95  2008      5     7    19  
96  2008      5     7    19  
97  2008      5     7    19  
98  2008      5     7    19  
99  2008      5     7    19
```

**The function chunks the data starting at 00:00 for each list, and I want it to begin from 16:00 from one day till 15:55 the next day**

Comment: Sample data would make this easier.  I'm not certain what your after but IIUC a clever solution would be to base your chunking on `df.Date_Time + pd.offsets.Hour(8)`

Comment: Edited. I hope this helps to make things clear.

Comment: Used your method as a placeholder for grouping. Thank you! Still figuring out the week issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['temp'] = df['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Time']
df.temp = pd.to_datetime(df.temp, infer_datetime_format=True)
df.temp = df.temp + pd.offsets.Hour(8)

g = df.groupby(df['temp'].dt.normalize())
df_single_day = []
for group in g:
    if len(group[1])> 1:
        df_single_day.append(group[1])
```

The above code produces the right answer. I have a slight (but unimportant issue) where the groups at the end of the week with time 16:00 are alone, so I just remove them with the if statement.

Still figuring out how to do something like dt.week where the week is from Sun-Sun given that my data begins on Mon and dt.week goes Mon-Mon...